# prove that every isometry Is also continous

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, isometry

Let $ (X,d_x) $ and $(Y,d_y)$ be metric spaces, an isometry $f:(x,d_x)\rightarrow (y,d_y)$
Is Always continous

Proof:

A function Is an isometry if keeps distances unaltered therfore $ \forall x_1,x_2\in X$ $ d_x(x_1,x_2)=d_y(f(x_1),f(X_2))$

And a function is continuous when the retro image of an open set is always open, in the case of metric spaces, balls are open sets ( we can create a base of balls) therefore is enough to prove that for each ball of Y , it is contained in a ball of x

Let's consider $y_0\in Y$ and $B_y (y_0, \epsilon):=${$y| d_y(y,y_0) $}

$\forall y\in  B_y (y_0, \epsilon)$

$ d_y( y,y_0)<\epsilon \implies$
$ d_x(f^{-1}(y),f{-1}(y_0)< \epsilon$

Therefore every ball of Y is also contained in a ball of X, the only problem I have is that I think that it is not correct to take the inverse function of $y_0,y$ therefore I think the proof is wrong.

Comment: It depends on whether you assume your isometry is bijective or only injective. If it is not surjective you may restrict to the image of $f$ with the subspace metric and topology to make $f$ surjective. You do get $d_Y(y,y_0)<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow d_X(f^{-1}(y),f^{-1}(y_0))< \epsilon$ which proves continuity of $f$ as $f^{-1}(Z)=f^{-1}(Z\cap f(X))$ for all $Z\subseteq Y$. Continuity by convergence of sequences bypasses this trick as you only take images, not inverse images. You can also work the other way around, with $f^{-1}:f(X)\rightarrow X$ which is a homeomorphism by the above.

Comment: The function Is not bijective, and i haven't done sequences yet in topology

Comment: There are 3 sketchy proofs in my comment, 2 of which work without sequences, so you can pick the 1st restricting the codomain to the image, $f(X)$, gives a sujective thus bijective isometry, or 2nd using the inverse of $f$ which is well defined on $f(X)$ gives a bijective isometry in the other direction. As i indicated you have to explain that inverse images of open sets in $f(X)$ are exactly inverse images of open sets in $Y$, in particular for balls centered at points not in $f(X)$. The intersection of such an open ball with $f(X)$ need not be an open ball in $f(X)$, but it is still open.

Comment: @Math1000 yes, i briefly looked at the question you linked to and i think my comment provides a correct reply to it. I have seen the first answer by Daniel Fischer and it provides still another slightly different proof, but using the concept of continuity at a point in terms of open sets (that yields essentially the proof in terms of sequences for a metric space), which must then, like for continuity by sequences, be related to what he calls "global continuity": the usual topological definition that inverse images of open sets are open.

Comment: You have it backwards. The inverse image of open sets in $Y$ being open in $X$ requires that for each $x, y = f(x)$, the inverse image of a ball in $Y$ contains a ball in $X$, not the other way around. The inverse image of a ball in $Y$ containing a ball in $X$ means for that any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(B_\epsilon(y))$, or equivalently that $f(B_\delta(x)) \subseteq B_\epsilon(y))$. That is, for all $x'\in X$ with $d_X(x,x') < \delta, d_Y(f(x), f(x')) = d_Y(y, f(x')) < \epsilon$. That is the condition you need to show.